# Visualization of numerical integration

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, homework

I have to do a project about numerical integration. My problem is visualizing my method.

My code:

```
Begin["private`"]
CMp[g_, y1_, y2_, m_] := 
  Module[{i = 0, summ = 0},
    While[i < m, summ = summ + g[y1 + i*(y2 - y1)/m]; i++];
    Return[N[summ*(y2 - y1)/m]]]
```

My teacher told me that I had to draw a integrand plot with `m` rectangles on it. I have no idea how can I do this. Any help?

Comment: Make rectangles of width equal to your iteration step and height equal to your function and display them side-by-side.

Comment: I don't know how to display them side-by-side.

Comment: Related/duplicates: [(15881)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15881), [(71994)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71994), [(104458)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104458)

Comment: How to display a set of rectangles and a result of numerical integration?

Comment: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/IntegrationByRiemannSums/

Comment: I can't use the same idea for the trapeze method. How can i display trapeziums by the ListLinePlot?

Comment: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheTrapezoidalRuleForIncreasingFunctions/

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to visualize the trapezoidal method. It's not the most elegant way. It's been written as a step-by-step module so the code will be easy to understand.

- `func` is the function to be integrated
- `xmin` is the lower bound
- `xmax` is the upper bound
- `steps` is how many steps to take when approximating the integral; i.e., how many trapezoids to use.
- `aspect` (optional argument) gives the aspect ratio for the plot. When not given, Mathematica chooses the value.

```
visualTrapezoidRule[func_, xmin_, xmax_, steps_, aspect_: Automatic] :=
   Module[{pts, verticals, caps},
     pts = Table[{x, func[x]}, {x, Subdivide[xmin, xmax, steps]}];
     verticals = Line[{{#[[1]], 0}, #}] & /@ pts;
     caps = Line @ pts;
     Graphics[{verticals, caps}, AspectRatio -> aspect, Axes -> True]]
```

Note: `func` must be a symbol bound to a function or pure function. This simplified implementation is not designed to take math expressions like `1 + Cos[x]`.

```
visualTrapezoidRule[Sqrt[1 - #^2] &, -1, 1, 10]
```

[image: plot1]

```
visualTrapezoidRule[Sin, 0, 2 π, 20, 1]
```

[image: plot2]

Comment: You are very welcoming to new comers with homework. :)